# SPI flash programming issues

Tags: c, memory, spi, dma, flash-memory

I am using STM32F429 CortexM4 in my application target board.  I have got external SPI flash(8MB) and external SDRAM(32MB) to overcome the size constraints on my chip.

Here I have separate project for .BMP image files which need to be used and to be programmed into SPI flash and then copy into SDRAM from flash.

But thing is as I have got multiple .c files for each image in this project, so here my question is whether it's possible to program each image object file into specific address location on flash using Whole project hex files?

Or else how do we make our data to reside in specific address location on flash?

Comment: What does this have to do with actionscript? Confused as to why the actionscript tag was added to this post.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any way to automatic save to SPI flash your image files from .c files included in project. When you include images as .c files they will be programmed to internal flash as a part of your output (bin/hex) file.
If you want to save free space of your internal flash, you need:

1. join your images in one file with a simple headers by any program    (you can write it or download)
2. download this file to SPI flash throught any interface (USART, USB or another), at this step must work your function that can to transfer incoming data to SPI flash
3. and now you can read files from flash, load it to ram and use for
   your purposes